# Continuity of positive operators

Tags: functional-analysis

How to prove that an positive linear operator $T:C[0,1]\to R $ in the sense that $T(f)\geq 0$ when $f\geq 0$ is bounded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $\|f\|_\infty \leq 1$. Then $-1\le f\le 1$ so
$-T(1) \le T(-1)\le T(f) \le T(1)$ so $\|T\| \le T(1)$.  In fact equality is achieved, since
$\|1\|_\infty = 1$.